# Hide/Show suggestions on click

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I made a mail check suggestion email input box if the user puts email:- *ss@gnail.com*, it will give suggestion *ss@gmail.com* and likewise.

Right now, the issue I am facing is, if the user gets any suggestions, then the user should be able to click on the suggested email and then suggestion should be hidden on click.

I used show hide method, but it doesn't show suggestion second time following hiding show approach I used. [image: picture].

if you see in the picture, its getting suggestion, once I will click on the suggestion, it will be corrected but again if the user writes some wrong email it doesn't show any suggestion.
Below is the code for my stackblitz.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-pdbyrg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put `this.hideSuggestion = false;` on top of the `suggestEmail(email)` event.

```
suggestEmail(email) {
    this.hideSuggestion = false; <!-- Added this line -->
    Mailcheck.run({
      email: email,
      domains: ['gmail.com', 'aol.com', 'hotmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'rediffmail.com', 'edu', 'msn.com',], 
      secondLevelDomains: ['domain', 'hotmail'], 
      topLevelDomains: ["com", "net", "org", "info"],
      suggested: (suggestion) => {

        if (suggestion) {

          this.suggestion = suggestion
          this.suggestedEmail = this.suggestion.full
        }
      },
      empty: function () {
      }
    });

  }
```

[Stacklblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-atz1zi)

Answer (score 1):

Why it doesn't show the second time? Because you never turn `hideSuggestion` to `false`. Solution would be completely implementation dependent, one of them could be not using `hideSuggestion` at all but setting `suggestion` to `null` once its been set to the `input`

```
<div *ngIf="suggestion" (click)="clickSuggestion()">{{suggestedEmail}}</div>

  clickSuggestion() {
    this.signupForm.get('userData.email').setValue(this.suggestedEmail);
    this.emailSuggestion = this.signupForm.get('userData.email').value;
    if (this.emailSuggestion === this.suggestedEmail) {
      this.suggestion = null;
    }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-zqnmtp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts